# How can I avoid jackson json pointers for encapsulated object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object that encapsulates a second object.  For example:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@fooId")
@Entity(name = "Foo")
@Table(name = "Foo")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Foo {
     @Column(name = "too")
     private String too;

     @Column(name = "baz")
     private String baz;

     @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
     @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_bar")
     private Bar newBar;

     /// blahblah -- setters and getters and constructors
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@newBarId")
@Entity(name = "Bar")
@Table(name = "Bar")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Bar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long Id;  //database generated ID

    @Column(name = "barString")
    private String barString;  //string

     /// blahblah -- setters and getters and constructors
}
```

When I use REST, I do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path="test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public String getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {
    List<Foo> myList = dao.findById(id);
    String rtn = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myList);

    return rtn;
}
```

When I get a big list, every time that there is a Foo with a duplicate Bar--it just drops a pointer, which throws off my Javascript on the front end.

Is there a way to get Jackson to stop giving me pointers for the encapsulated objects and give me the object every time?

Thanks in advance.

ETA: I'm on another computer, but it will come out something like this:

```js
[
 {"@fooId" : 2, "too" : "basdf", "baz" : "asdf", "newBar" : { "@newBarId": 1, "id": 123, "barString" : "barString},
 {"@fooId": 3, "too" : "basafdsdf", "baz" : "asasdfdf", "newBar" : 1}
]
```

Where the second newBar is no longer an object, but a pointer to a previous one.  Hopefully this makes this clearer.

I have already looked through Hibernate and my search results--they come back with the Bar object every time.  So...it's something with ObjectMapper, but I don't know what.

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of what you mean?

Comment: Just an aside: why not use `@GetMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`?

Comment: @vapurrmaid - because I'm not quite done upgrading everything.

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the full type definitions and the ObjectMapper configuration?

Comment: Can it be because of your DataBase query?, I'm not sure but it sounds like there is some kind of LEFT JOIN issue going on before even you persist it to the JSON

Comment: @newbo, do you use `JsonIdentityInfo` annotation? Could you show how `ObjectMapper` is configured in your app?

Comment: @newbo, it could be either `JsonIdentityInfo` or `JsonManagedReference` annotations that cause such behavior. without the full source code of the classes involved, we cannot help you

Comment: There are no left joins. Every Foo has 1 Bar, but a Bar may be associated with many Foos.  The object mapper is ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Comment: @newbo, what do you mean "there is a Foo with a duplicate Bar"?, can you post what did you got?

Comment: @parlad - If 

Foo1 is related to Bar1, 
Foo2 is related to Bar2, and 
Foo3 is related to Bar1, 

then Foo3 will get the pointer to the identity field (@newBarId) of Bar1, rather than a serialized object of Bar1.  Foo1 and Foo2 will have serialized objects, Foo3 will have a number.

Comment: Michał and Sharon - It tentatively looks like you guys got me on the right track and the @JsonIdentityInfo might be the problem.  I have to go through the regression tests, but that might be the answer.  I had a huge problem with recursive objects a few releases ago and I put them everywhere, but it might be I was hitting a fly with a nuke and need to peel them back a bit.

Comment: @newbo, do you have a back reference from `Bar` to `Foo`, something like `private Foo foo` in `Bar` class? `JsonIdentityInfo` is not a solution for every problem.

Comment: @MichałZiober - I did end up removing JsonIdentityInfo and it did resolve it.  I have a ticket now to re-evaluate this so that I can figure out how to avoid it.  I put it in during some rapid prototyping because I ended up with a bunch of circular references while I was figuring out Jackson and the data structures.  I can't give you an answer credit in a comment, but I did look at yours and Sharon's comments and that put me on the right track.